# Because "flutter_app" depends on fluttertoast 4.0.2 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

Because "flutter_app" depends on fluttertoast 4.0.2 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.
This is my pubspec.yaml file

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0"
module:
  androidX: true
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: 0.1.2
  google_maps_flutter: 0.5.29
  google_map_location_picker: 3.3.3
  mvc_pattern: 6.1.3+2
  global_configuration: 1.5.0
  http: 0.12.2
  html: 0.14.0+3
  shared_preferences: 0.5.8
  flutter_html: 1.0.2
  flutter_svg: 0.18.0
  location: 3.0.2
  flutter_inappbrowser: 2.0.2
  url_launcher: 5.5.0
  firebase_messaging: 6.0.16
  cached_network_image: 2.2.0+1
  fluttertoast: 4.0.2
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: 0.3.2
  intl_utils: 1.6.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

The error I'm getting is this

```
Because markets depends on fluttertoast 4.0.2 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_application...                     
pub get failed (1; Because markets depends on fluttertoast 4.0.2 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.)
```

Answer (score 3):

fluttertoast latest version is 7.0.2 ,

Since couple of your Package seem outdated to me , try `flutter pub outdated` to see the latest verion of package and update  change your pubspec.yaml accordingly.

comment on this answer if it still exists.

Comment: Whenever Any Answer Solves your problem , make sure to mark that as an answer and upvote it

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
fluttertoast: 4.0.2
```

With

```
fluttertoast: any
```

Comment: using 'any' is not a good approach especially in live/prod check this: dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies